# Link Button to multi view in a different web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I made few link buttons to one of my web forms to link to another web for that has multiview with five views. If the user for example clicked on the link the the word "Toys". This should automatically direct the user to the multi view in another form that is associated with the Toys and the same thing can be with other categories. How do I achieve this since I know I can link multi views in a web form but I ignore how to link a link button to a multi view in another web form! Any help please....

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("MoreDetails.aspx?MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1");
}
```

This code is not working and doesn't show anything! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how query strings work. Here is a good help page for learning querystrings.

[**Querystrings**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)

You'd have to do something more like this:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("MoreDetails.aspx?view=1");
}
```

Then on your MoreDetails page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var qs = Request.Querystring["view"];
   if(qs != null)
   {
      if(qs == "1")
      {
         MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: It works and very helpful link with useful information about thanks:)